# Equation with logarithms and absolute value

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value, ratio

I have this equation:
$$
\ln\frac{2-|y-1|}{1-|y|} = \ln x
$$
which becomes 
$$
\ln(2-|y-1|)-\ln(1-|y|) = \ln x.
$$

Can the first term in LHS be written as $\ln(2)-\ln(|y-1|)\implies\ln(2)-\ln(|y|)-\ln(|1|)$ and the second term as $\ln(1)-\ln(|y|)$?

How does one solve for $y$?

Answer (score 1):

No. In general $$\ln(a-b)=\ln(a)-\ln (b)$$
if and only if 
$$a-b=\frac ab,\ a-b\gt 0,\ a\gt 0,\ b\gt 0.$$

To solve
$$\frac{2-|y-1|}{1-|y|}=x$$
for $y$, separate it into three cases as $y\le 0,0\lt y\le 1,1\lt y.$ But note that $$1-|y|\not=0\iff y\not=\pm1.$$

Case 1 : If $y\le 0$, then we have
$$\frac{2-(-(y-1))}{1-(-y)}=x\Rightarrow x=1.$$
Note that $y\le 0$ can be any real number except $-1$.

Case 2 : If $0\lt y\lt 1$, then we have
$$\frac{2-(-(y-1))}{1-y}=x\Rightarrow y+1=x(1-y)\Rightarrow y(1+x)=x-1\Rightarrow y=\frac{x-1}{1+x}$$because $x\gt 0\Rightarrow 1+x\not=0$.

Case 3 : If $y\gt 1$, then we have
$$\frac{2-(y-1)}{1-y}=x\Rightarrow -y+3=x(1-y)\Rightarrow y(-1+x)=x-3\Rightarrow y=\frac{x-3}{x-1}$$
because $x\not=1$.

Comment: So, how would I handle that term?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Yours is not an equation, it is just an expression. What is your real question?

Comment: @giomasce well on the RHS there is a variable ln(x). My goal is to derive an expression for y. So, only y should be on the LHS and all the other terms should be on the right

Comment: @nashthung: Can you write the equation? What is the RHS?

Comment: @mathlove  RHS= right hand side   

'ln((2−|y−1|)/(1−|y|))= ln (x)'

Comment: @nashthung: Then, you can have $$\frac{2-|y-1|}{1-|y|}=x.$$

Comment: @mathlove Okay. 

now can I separate |y-1| as |y|-|1|. Also can |1| be equal to 1.

Comment: @nashthung: No! You cannot. Separate it into three cases as $y\le 0,0\lt y\le 1,y\gt 1$. Do you understand $|x|=x$ if $x\ge 0$. $|x|=-x$ if $x\lt 0$?

Comment: hmmm.. okay! thank you very much @mathlove

Comment: @nashthung: I added the cases. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to bother with logarithm for this simple question. First, you observe that if $x \leq 0$ the RHS makes no sense, so there are no solutions. If instead $x > 0$, then the equation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{2-|y-1|}{1-|y|} = x,
$$
since the logarithm is an injective function. Now you should be able to solve it by yourself. For instance, try to plot a graph of the LHS.

Remember that you have to discard solutions which give non-positive values for $x$.

Comment: okay. But i want to obtain an expression for y. How do I deal with the modulus?

y has to be obtained from a given value of x.